# Is it possible to create a chain of source maps?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, minify

I work on a TypeScript file `foo.ts`.  Once my workflow is done with it, I have the following files:

```
foo.ts
foo.js         // generated                   - referenced by page in QA
foo.js.map     // source map between foo.ts and foo.js
foo.min.js     // minified version of foo.js  - referenced by page in Production
foo.min.js.map // source map between foo.js and foo.min.js
```

Debugging in QA works great, since devtools lets me work in `foo.ts` (e.g. in TypeScript).

However, once I am in production, `foo.min.js` is referenced by the page and devtools only let me debug with `foo.js`.  It seems that it can't figure out the chain of source maps from `foo.min.js` to `foo.ts`.

Is there a trick that I am missing to allow me to chain the source maps?

Comment: You just have to look for TS minified, as otherwise it just won't work

Comment: @Akxe I am not sure what you are saying.

Comment: Provide us the configuration you use in pipeline TS compilation, minification.

Comment: @Akxe Visual Studio 2019 compiles .ts to .js when I save it and creates a source map.  Then the Bundler & Minifier plugin takes that .js and creates .min.js and the source map for that.

Comment: That will never work indeed. You need one system to do both of the steps, they cannot communicate in between.